# cesiumjs polyline length issue

Tags: javascript, maps, google-earth-plugin, cesiumjs

I am trying to draw a polyline on CesiumJs globe.This polyline actually makes a circle. Here is currentLine is an array. like `[x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2....]` Whenever the length is greater than 549 or in other sense when the points in the polyline exceeds 183 the cesium modules gives the error:

> An error occurred while rendering. Rendering has stopped.
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
>       at Function.i.subtract (/include/Cesium-1.7.1/Build/Cesium/Workers/createGeometry.js:73:6359)
>       at Function.v.createGeometry (/include/Cesium-1.7.1/Build/Cesium/Workers/createPolylineGeometry.js:60:28125)
>       at n (include/Cesium-1.7.1/Build/Cesium/Workers/createPolylineGeometry.js:60:29743)
>       at a (include/Cesium-1.7.1/Build/Cesium/Workers/createGeometry.js:76:31234)
>       at DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope. (include/Cesium-1.7.1/Build/Cesium/Workers/createGeometry.js:76:30500)

This is the code

```
var newLine=viewer.entities.add({
                 id:lineId,
                 name : getModelName(id),
                polyline:{
                    positions : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArrayHeights(currentLine),
                    material : new Cesium.Color()
                }
            });
```

Kindly help me how to solve this problem :) Thanks I was wondering if there are any duplicates so i removed all the duplicates but then the array was no more of the multiple of 3 and it was not accepted as a valid polyline :/

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this.  I made some sample code that puts 1000 points in a polyline that stretches around the globe, and it works.  Is there anything else you're doing that could cause the problem?

Comment: I am drawing polyline that is circle. may be it is because of duplication of points or something like that??? I am getting this error for only that case when the polyline represents a circle